# Metal Indirect command buffer with multiple instances and multiple LOD

Tags: metal

I have the following Metal shader, that computes an indirect command buffer for a set of different meshes/submeshes, with multiple instances for each.

```
struct ICBContainer {
    command_buffer icb [[id(0)]];
};

struct ICBMesh {
    // Mesh data
    constant float *vertices;
    constant float *uv;
    constant float *tangents;
    constant float *bitangents;
    // Submesh data
    constant uint *indices;
    constant float *materials;
};

kernel void model_encode(
    uint meshId [[thread_position_in_grid]],
    device ICBContainer *icbContainer [[buffer(BUF_ICB)]],
    constant ICBMesh *meshes [[buffer(BUF_MESHES)]],
    constant MTLDrawIndexedPrimitivesIndirectArguments *draw [[buffer(BUF_DRAW)]],
    constant InstanceData *instances [[buffer(BUF_INSTANCES)]],
    constant Uniforms &uniforms [[buffer(BUF_UNIFORMS)]])
{
    ICBMesh mesh = meshes[meshId];
    MTLDrawIndexedPrimitivesIndirectArguments drawArgs = draw[meshId];
    
    render_command cmd(icbContainer->icb, meshId);
    cmd.set_vertex_buffer(&uniforms, BUF_UNIFORMS);
    cmd.set_vertex_buffer(mesh.vertices, BUF_VERTEX);
    cmd.set_vertex_buffer(mesh.uv, BUF_UV);
    cmd.set_vertex_buffer(mesh.tangents, BUF_TANGENT);
    cmd.set_vertex_buffer(mesh.bitangents, BUF_BITANGENT);
    cmd.set_fragment_buffer(mesh.materials, BUF_MATERIAL);
    cmd.set_vertex_buffer(instances, BUF_INSTANCES);
    cmd.draw_indexed_primitives(
        primitive_type::triangle,
        drawArgs.indexCount,
        mesh.indices + drawArgs.indexStart,
        drawArgs.instanceCount,
        drawArgs.baseVertex,
        drawArgs.baseInstance);
}
```

It's working fine, but now I would like to provide different meshes at different LOD (0, 1, 2), but with the same list of instances, and make my compute shader calculate the LOD for each instance and filter the draw calls.

I added an argument (lod) to the ICBMesh structure, and the mesh buffer now contains all the different meshes for all different LODs.

```
struct ICBMesh {
    uint lod;
    // Mesh data
    constant float *vertices;
    constant float *uv;
    constant float *tangents;
    constant float *bitangents;
    // Submesh data
    constant uint *indices;
    constant float *materials;
};
```

Now, it's calling model_encode() for all LOD versions of my models, with the same list of instances. So, it is rendering all the LOD versions for each instances.

What I would like to do in my shader is calculate the LOD of all my instances (in function of the distance to camera), and draw only the instances whose LOD corresponds to the current mesh's LOD, without having to calculate instance LOD on the CPU and provide different buffers at every frame.

I guess it implies that I make a new array containing the filtered instances and pass this array to the render command and draw call. Something like this:

```
cmd.set_vertex_buffer(**filteredInstances**, BUF_INSTANCES);
cmd.draw_indexed_primitives(
    primitive_type::triangle,
    drawArgs.indexCount,
    mesh.indices + drawArgs.indexStart,
    **filteredInstancesCount**,
    drawArgs.baseVertex,
    **0**);
```

But how can I make this array of filtered instances without knowing its size in advance?
And does this approach make sense in the first place?

Comment: I think you would have like an array of your mesh structs per mesh instead of one mesh, each element of the array representing a lod of the same mesh. and then you would individually just encode a draw for a specific lod for a specific mesh in the simplest case.

Comment: Do you mean that I have no option other than making the LOD computation (and frustum culling, btw) on the CPU before sending the buffers? I was looking for a GPU-driven solution, without having to update the buffers at every frame.

Comment: That's not what I said. I said that you have to have defined lods for your meshes as in, you need to somehow define the vertices and indices for each lod. Then you can choose the lod on GPU and draw that. And cull as well. If you are gonna use culling, you need to use an indirect command buffer that's big enough, and then either use indirect version of execute `executeCommandsInBuffer:indirectBuffer:indirectBufferOffset:` to specify the range of commands on GPU or you can just execute the whole buffer, but then you might need to run `optimizeIndirectCommandBuffer:withRange:` first

Comment: Thank you so much, but I think I'm completely missing the point. I already have my vertices and indices defined by LOD, in the ICBMesh structure. The model_encode() function is called for each mesh and each LOD, but each time with the same buffer containing all instances; and I'm trying to figure out how I can filter that list of instances in function of the current mesh LOD, so that I can still encode multi-instance draw calls in my ICB... Or do I need to call it once per instance instead and encode one draw call per instance? (but that would require a huge ICB)

Comment: I see. I mean, you definitely do not need to call draw on each lod, for each instance. But in case you have a lot of instanced geometry, you would need to come up with an algorithm to bin those instances into lod buckets if you still want to issue instaned draws. Or yes, you can increase icb size and issue single draw per-instance at a specific lod it needs, to start things off.

Comment: The solution I have found is to create a buffer (uint *) for each LOD, filled by a new compute shader. Each of these buffers contains the list of instance ids I want to draw at each specific LOD, in a compact form, so that I can use it as a list of instance ids in my draw calls, along with the global list of instance data, so that I can retrieve the instance data in my vertex shader.
Now I have to figure out how I can parallelise this filtering compute shader, and also avoid recreating these buffers at every frame... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I have found is to create a buffer (uint *) for each LOD, filled by a new compute shader.

```
kernel void instance_filter(
uint instanceId [[thread_position_in_grid]],
constant CameraUniforms &camera [[buffer(BUF_CAMERA)]],
constant InstanceData *instances [[buffer(BUF_INSTANCES)]],
device atomic_uint *lod0 [[buffer(BUF_LOD0)]],
device atomic_uint *lod1 [[buffer(BUF_LOD1)]],
device atomic_uint *lod2 [[buffer(BUF_LOD2)]])
{...}
```

These buffers contain the number of instances (first position) and the list of instance ids I want to draw for each specific LOD, in a compact form, so that I can use them in my instanced draw calls:

```
kernel void model_encode(
uint meshId [[thread_position_in_grid]],
device ICBContainer *icbContainer [[buffer(BUF_ICB)]],
constant Uniforms &uniforms [[buffer(BUF_UNIFORMS)]],
constant ICBMesh *meshes [[buffer(BUF_MESHES)]],
constant MTLDrawIndexedPrimitivesIndirectArguments *draw [[buffer(BUF_DRAW)]],
constant InstanceData *instances [[buffer(BUF_INSTANCES)]],
constant uint *lod0 [[buffer(BUF_LOD0)]],
constant uint *lod1 [[buffer(BUF_LOD1)]],
constant uint *lod2 [[buffer(BUF_LOD2)]])
{
ICBMesh mesh = meshes[meshId];
MTLDrawIndexedPrimitivesIndirectArguments drawArgs = draw[meshId];
constant uint *indices = lod_select(mesh.lod, lod0, lod1, lod2);
uint numInstances = indices[0];
render_command cmd(icbContainer->icb, meshId);
cmd.set_vertex_buffer(&uniforms, BUF_UNIFORMS);
cmd.set_vertex_buffer(mesh.vertices, BUF_VERTEX);
cmd.set_vertex_buffer(mesh.uv, BUF_UV);
cmd.set_vertex_buffer(mesh.tangents, BUF_TANGENT);
cmd.set_vertex_buffer(mesh.bitangents, BUF_BITANGENT);
cmd.set_fragment_buffer(mesh.materials, BUF_MATERIAL);
cmd.set_vertex_buffer(instances, BUF_INSTANCES);
cmd.set_vertex_buffer(indices, BUF_INDICES);
cmd.draw_indexed_primitives(
    primitive_type::triangle,
    drawArgs.indexCount,
    mesh.indices + drawArgs.indexStart,
    numInstances,
    drawArgs.baseVertex,
    1); // ignore the first element (numInstances)
}
```

The instanced draw calls now use indices to my filtered list as instance ids. Then, in my vertex shader, I get the instance data from "instances" indirectly, by reading the actual instance id in the passed "indices" buffer.